# Using static method that include once and initialize an object in Yii2

Tags: php, oop, yii2

I have created the following tools class in vendors of Yii2 application:

```
//@vendor/saidbakr/tools/FoxText.php
namespace FoxTools;
class FoxText
{
  public static function normalise($txt)
  {
    include(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."/I18N/Arabic.php");  

     $norm2 = new \I18N_Arabic('Normalise');        

     return $norm2->stripTashkeel($txt);

  }
}
```

When using `FoxText::normalise()` inside a loop or reusing it inside any other block of the code, I have got the following Error:

> PHP Compile Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Cannot redeclare class I18N_Arabic_Normalise
>   1. in C:\xampp-2\htdocs\feqh-site\vendor\I18N\Arabic\Normalise.php

I tried to use `include_once` and define the method without `static` and initializing as dynamic variable

`$p = new FoxTools\FoxText()`
then `$p->normalise()` but it failed too. I also tried to:

```
use FoxTools\FoxText;
use FoxTools\FoxText as text2;
use FoxTools\FoxText as text3;
```

and it succeeded but it is not useful in loop.

What I would like to mention again, ** it works fine if I used it once**

Answer (score 1):

Use `namespaces` instead of `include` or `require`. This is the [recommended Yii2 method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-upgrade-from-v1.html#namespace) for importing files. Assuming `Arabic.php` is in the `\I18N` namespace:

```
namespace FoxTools;
use \I18N\Arabic;
class FoxText
{
...
```

Alternatively, you can use `require_once` instead of `include`:

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."/I18N/Arabic.php");
```

Comment: The problem, indeed, is in the Arabic library that I use. It has not support of namespaces yet. so using namespacing and `use` is not an option

Comment: Have you considered using Yii2's [I18N implementation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-i18n.html)?

Comment: I have to use the implementation of the specific library it is dedicated for Arabic and contains a lot of features supporting many Arabic text features. it can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ar-php/files/)